# CASE WHEN POSTGRESQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, case, postgresql-9.5

Wondering if CASE WHEN in postgres can go beyond these kind of examples:

```
SELECT title,
       length,
       CASE
           WHEN length> 0
                AND length <= 50 THEN 'Short'
           WHEN length > 50
                AND length <= 120 THEN 'Medium'
           WHEN length> 120 THEN 'Long'
       END duration
FROM film
ORDER BY title;
```

I'd like to use field values instead of hard coded values. Currently I have to do something like this to get a correct result:

```
CASE
    WHEN schema_z.table1.type_code IS NULL THEN
    CASE COALESCE(schema_a.tableA.description, schema_b.tableB.description)
        WHEN 'Social Worker'::text THEN 'SW'::character varying
        WHEN 'Admin'::text THEN 'ADM'::character varying
        ELSE COALESCE(schema_a.tableA.description, schema_b.tableB.description)
    END
END AS code
```

Is there a way to not hard code the description and code in the case statement, and be able to do something like this?

```
CASE
    WHEN schema_z.table1.type_code IS NULL THEN
    CASE COALESCE(schema_a.tableA.description, schema_b.tableB.description)
        WHEN schema_a.tableA.description = schema_z.master_table.description or schema_b.tableB.description = schema_z.master_table.description THEN schema_z.master_table.code::character varying
        ELSE COALESCE(schema_a.tableA.description, schema_b.tableB.description)
    END
END AS code
```

Where schema_z.master_table is the table saving the codes and description catalog. The other tables are using either the code or description of the catalog table.

Usually table schema_z.table1 has the record for specific filters, but others the value has to be extracted from one of the other tables (schema_a.tableA, schema_b.tableB) that are a match for the master_Table in the description.

How can I compare the description of tableA or tableB against the master_table in a CASE statement? When attempting the above, I am getting an error `column schema_z.master_table.description does not exist`

Thanks

Comment: It works as you want in your last example, by either joining schema_z.master_table or using a subselect in the case.

Comment: Did you try  `CASE  WHEN  COALESCE(schema_a.tableA.description, schema_b.tableB.description) = schema_z.master_table.description THEN schema_z.master_table.code::character varying ELSE ...` ?